# Learning Russian language

Tags: discussion

I am a newcomer here. I want to learn Russian language, but I didn't understand the functions of the site in order to write messages for those who know Russian. Who will help me?

Answer (score 3):

Thank you for your interest in Russian and for visiting our site!

This site is a Q&A site. What we do here is we ask and answer questions about Russian: concise, relatively short questions which can be answered with concise, relatively short answers.

Think of it like of a visit to Home Depot when you're building a house.

"Hey excuse me, sir, do you carry 2x4 lumber?" is an okay question for Home Depot, because the answer is likely going to be "Sure, they're over there on aisle 24, we have pine and whitewood".

However, this is really something you could look up on your phone.

"I need it for a header, would the pine do?" is also a good question.

The answer you're likely to get (if you're lucky and come across a qualified person) is "can I see the blueprint? nah, you'd probably need something more sturdy for that, pine is way too soft".

This is a good question: it takes a minute to ask, a minute to answer and requires some expertise.

"I need to build a house, what do I need to do?" is not such a good question for a DYI store.

The answer you're likely to get is "well, sir, I'd enjoy to stand there and have a chat with you, but I really need to load this pallet and you're not supposed to be here anyway, this isle is closed and I'm operating the forklift!"

Well, you get the idea.

So, just look around and see what kind of questions people ask. We have the score system: questions and answers which are considered good by other participants get more scores and are bumped to the top. Look for such questions, they are probably good.